# Sveltekit + Typescript: Environment variables build error

Tags: typescript, types, sveltekit

I want to use environment variables in my Sveltekit app - it works fine on dev server, but I get this build error:

`Error: 'PUBLIC_KEY' is not exported by $env/static/public, imported by src/routes/+layout.svelte`

So Svelte has this module that helps with env stuff: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$env-static-public

I have a simple .env file like this:

```
PUBLIC_KEY=123
```

Now the IDE throws the same type error like the build error, but I can fix that by adding this to my `types.d.ts` file:

```js
declare module '$env/static/public' {
    export const PUBLIC_KEY: string;
}
```

Now the type error in my IDE is gone, for testing I just add this to my +layout.svelte file:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { PUBLIC_KEY } from '$env/static/public';

</script>
<div>{ PUBLIC_KEY }</div>
```

The content 123 is rendered on dev server, so it works. However, if I run `npm run build`, the error from above occurs. Even putting a `@ts-ignore` above the import doesn't help.
So my question is: what do I have to do to make TS play along?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I found the answer - in a comment of the PR for that feature. Would be nice if that was in the documentation.

However, for those who face that issue and land here: you have to run `svelte-kit sync` - it will create a type file based upon your .env files.
You can use `npm run check` - this includes the sync command.

You don't need to write the types yourself like I did in my question! Just run `npm run check`.

Comment: I use Javascript and get the same  error during build time (I use container to build the  production code and this is where the error appears though).

Comment: @TomaszPlonka Did you forget to copy the .env file in your Dockerfile?

Comment: @Stiegi please can you link to the comment in the PR for the feature?

Comment: sure: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/pull/5663#issue-1313924415

Comment: For me the `svelte-kit sync` was not present, but running `npx @sveltejs/kit sync` helped

Comment: `npm run check` worked for me. `svelte-kit sync` didn't do anything however.

Comment: Running `npm run check` works for me and add the env variable to `.svelte-kit/ambient.d.ts` in `declare module '$env/static/private'` correctly but when I then run `npm run build`, it removes the variable from it... any clue why?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution, check whether or not your env variable is prefixed with 'PUBLIC'. If yes, you can import it from the module '$env/static/public'. If not, you can import it from the module '$env/static/private'