# Typescript error with Sveltekit environment variables: RollupError: "PUBLIC_XXX" is not exported by "$env/dynamic/public"

Tags: sveltekit

I have this line of code in `src/routes/+page.svelte`

```
    import {PUBLIC_SUPABASE_KEY} from '$env/dynamic/public';
```

When this builds on CI, I get this error:

```
@cozemble/frontend-main-app:build: RollupError: "PUBLIC_SUPABASE_KEY" is not exported by "$env/dynamic/public", imported by "src/routes/+page.svelte".
@cozemble/frontend-main-app:build:     at error (file:///Users/mikehogan/repos/personal/cozemble/monorepo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.9.1/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:1967:30)
@cozemble/frontend-main-app:build:     at Module.error (file:///Users/mikehogan/repos/personal/cozemble/monorepo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.9.1/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:12962:16)
@cozemble/frontend-main-app:build:     at Module.traceVariable (file:///Users/mikehogan/repos/personal/cozemble/monorepo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.9.1/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:13345:29)
@cozemble/frontend-main-app:build:     at ModuleScope.findVariable (file:///Users/mikehogan/repos/personal/cozemble/monorepo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.9.1/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:11826:39)
@cozemble/frontend-main-app:build:     at FunctionScope.findVariable (file:///Users/mikehogan/repos/personal/cozemble/monorepo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.9.1/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:6687:38)
@cozemble/frontend-main-app:build:     at ChildScope.findVariable (file:///Users/mikehogan/repos/personal/cozemble/monorepo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.9.1/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:6687:38)
@cozemble/frontend-main-app:build:     at Identifier.bind (file:///Users/mikehogan/repos/personal/cozemble/monorepo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.9.1/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:7782:40)
@cozemble/frontend-main-app:build:     at CallExpression.bind (file:///Users/mikehogan/repos/personal/cozemble/monorepo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.9.1/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:5575:28)
@cozemble/frontend-main-app:build:     at CallExpression.bind (file:///Users/mikehogan/repos/personal/cozemble/monorepo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.9.1/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:9299:15)
@cozemble/frontend-main-app:build:     at VariableDeclarator.bind (file:///Users/mikehogan/repos/personal/cozemble/monorepo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.9.1/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:5579:23)
@cozemble/frontend-main-app:build:  ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
@cozemble/frontend-main-app:build: ERROR: command finished with error: command (/Users/mikehogan/repos/personal/cozemble/monorepo/frontend/main-app) pnpm run build exited (1)
```

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73865669/sveltekit-typescript-environment-variables-build-error) suggests that the right Typescripts get generated from a `.env` file when you run `npm run check`.  But it is my understanding that `.env` files are **NOT** to be checked into CI.

So this really easy approach to env vars in SvelteKit is defeating me.  What is the right approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to set the variable to *anything* so it is picked up by SvelteKit.

This can be done any number of ways, e.g. by running a command before the build to set it. What that command should look like depends on the build platform. Or if you are using a build pipeline with a GUI you probably could set the variable there.

Comment: My CI is Github actions, and my app hosting is Vercel.  I _want_ to set the env var in Vercel, because the app runs there, but I do _not_ want to have to set it also in Github actions where the app is only being built.  Does that sound wrong?

Comment: Actually, you should not need to do anything. The `dynamic` module is defined in a way to accept anything starting with `PUBLIC_`. Is your build pipeline missing a `svelte-kit sync` call? (And as I said, **any** value would do, including an empty string...)

Comment: Is one of the pages using the key pre-rendered? If so, you *have to* set the value, otherwise it cannot be read at build time, including CI.