# Environment Variables in SvelteKit Throwing Error on Deployment to Vercel

Tags: vercel, sveltekit

I am working with SvelteKit and deploying to Vercel. I am using environment variables and having a tough time getting this to work. The error below shows on my Vercel Dashboard when I push to Git.

```
RollupError: "PRIVATE_API_KEY" is not exported by "$env/static/private", imported by "src/routes/account/+layout.server.js".
```

I found the following in the [docs](https://vercel.com/docs/frameworks/sveltekit). It shows creating a +layout.server.js file and then states you can pull that into the +layout.svelte or +page.svelte components through data.

layout.server.js

```
import { PRIVATE_API_KEY } from '$env/static/private';
 
/** @type {import('./$types').LayoutServerLoad} */
export function load() {
  return {
    deploymentGitBranch: PRIVATE_API_KEY,
  };
}
```

+layout.svelte

```
<script>
  /** @type {import('./$types').LayoutData} */
  export let data;
</script>
 
<p>This staging environment was deployed from {data.deploymentGitBranch}.</p>
```

My .env file is as shown below.

```
# Public
PUBLIC_API_KEY=public


# Private
PRIVATE_API_KEY=123456789
```

I did search through this site and found the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73865669/sveltekit-typescript-environment-variables-build-error) but this seems dated and I could not get it to work. Even after following these steps the issue persists?

How do I resolve this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a variable *not* known at build time, so it should also not be imported from the static environment variables.

Use [`$env/dynamic/private`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$env-dynamic-private) instead.

> This module provides access to runtime environment variables, as defined by the platform you're running on.

The `.env` file will not be loaded, so the variables have to be configured in Vercel.

Comment: This did not correct the issue. The same error message is thrown with dynamic in place of static. RollupError: "PRIVATE_API_KEY" is not exported by "$env/dynamic/private", imported by "src/routes/account/+layout.server.js".

Comment: Did you configure the variables in Vercel? The `.env` file will probably *not* be loaded.

Comment: I did not. Thank you! This was the issue I was having. I did not see this in the docs.